# How to disable browser Save Login Info in Flutter Web Hummingbird

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, hummingbird

I have a simple Login Page with Firebase Authentication. I would like the Browser (chrome) to stop asking 
me to save Login Info. Is there a way to disable the browser attempting to 'Save Login Info' (Username and Password) with every login.  How can I achieve this ? Any help is appreciated.  Thank You.

```
                        RawKeyboardListener(
                          onKey: (RawKeyEvent key) {
                            print('keyCode1: ${key.data.logicalKey}');
                            print('keyCode2: ${key.data.logicalKey.keyId}');
                            print('keyCode3: ${key.data.logicalKey.keyLabel}');
                            if (key.data.logicalKey.keyId == 4295426091) {
                              print('go to next cell............?????  !!!!!!   node:$_passwordFocus');
                              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocus);
                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(width: 500,
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: TextFormField(
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white), cursorColor: Colors.white,
                                controller: emailController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Email',
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                                ),
                                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Email Required' : null,
                                onSaved: (val) => _email = val,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusNode: _emailFocus,
                        ),

                        ///////////////

                        RawKeyboardListener(
                          onKey: (RawKeyEvent key) {
                            if (key.data.logicalKey.keyId == 4295426088) {
                              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                _formKey.currentState.save();
//                                _auth.add(LoginEvent(_email, _password));
                                auth.signInExistingFireBaseEmail(_email, _password);
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(width: 500,
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: TextFormField(
                                focusNode: _passwordFocus,
                                controller: passwordController,
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                obscureText: true,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password', labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Password Required' : null,
                                onSaved: (val) => _password = val,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusNode: _passFocus,
                        ),
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html >

<head >
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>grid_three</title>
</head>
<body>


<!--<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>-->
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>

//Firebase Init...



<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```